# display date from current dateto next six days

Tags: vb.net

I am using this code for display dates from current date to next six days.
if any other code for display date like this. please help

```
Private Sub Displaydate()
    cn.ConnectionString = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings("DataConnectionString")
    lblDateday.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dddd")
    lblMonthdate.Text = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("dd MMMM ")
    lblDateday2.Text = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("dddd")
    lblMonthdate2.Text = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(1).ToString("dd MMMM ")
    lblDateday3.Text = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString("dddd")
    lblMonthdate3.Text = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(2).ToString("dd MMMM ")
    lblDateday4.Text = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString("dddd")
    lblMonthdate4.Text = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(3).ToString("dd MMMM ")
    lblDateday5.Text = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(4).ToString("dddd")
    lblMonthdate5.Text = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(4).ToString("dd MMMM ")
    lblDateday6.Text = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).ToString("dddd")
    lblMonthdate6.Text = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(5).ToString("dd MMMM ")
    lblDateday7.Text = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(6).ToString("dddd")
    lblMonthdate7.Text = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(6).ToString("dd MMMM ")
End Sub
```

the output is

Wednesday    Thursday      Friday      Saturday      Sunday         Monday      Tuesday

21 November  22 November  23 November  24 November  25 November  26 November   27November

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the things you handle into arrays and then do loops instead.

Assign Lists globally

```
Dim DateDayList as List(of Label) = new List(of Label)
Dim MonthDayList as List(of Label) = new List(of Label)
```

Add all dateDay labels to list in the correct order inside the Initialize sub.

```
DateDayList.Add(lblDateDay)
DateDayList.Add(lblDateDay2)
etc.
```

Do the same with the Month day labels.

Then simply do this:

```
for i as Integer = 0 To 6
   DateDayList(i).Text = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(i).ToString("dddd")
   MonthDayList(i).Text = System.DateTime.Now.AddDays(i).ToString("dd MMMM ")
next
```